# Can't Archive project Xcode Firebase

Tags: xcode, firebase, swiftui

My project builds fine in the simulator and in my iPhone, but when I try to archive it I get the following warning:

> warning: ignoring file /Users/ricardmarsalcastan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-gebktsshgacruvaqsitbrpluviem/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/leveldb-library/leveldb.framework/leveldb, building for iOS-armv7 but attempting to link with file built for iOS-arm64

And this errors, all from firebase database:

```
Undefined symbol: leveldb::WriteBatch::WriteBatch()
Undefined symbol: leveldb::WriteBatch::Clear()
Undefined symbol: leveldb::Status::ToString() const
Undefined symbol: leveldb::DB::Open(leveldb::Options const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, leveldb::DB**)
Undefined symbol: leveldb::WriteBatch::Delete(leveldb::Slice const&)
Undefined symbol: leveldb::WriteBatch::~WriteBatch()
Undefined symbol: leveldb::WriteBatch::Put(leveldb::Slice const&, leveldb::Slice const&)
Undefined symbol: leveldb::Options::Options()
```

This is my podfile

```
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
    pod 'Firebase/Storage'
    pod 'GeoFire', :git => 'https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc.git'
```

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

**I got the same issue and have resolved it by doing the below steps.**

1. Update all your firebase pods
2. Delete the Derived folder
3. Clean & Build XCode Project
4. Try achieving again works for me.